# Different output for the same set of input data, but in different order

Tags: c++, visual-studio, console-application

Why do I get different output when I execute this code:

```
int n;
int b[99];
int money = 0;

int min()
{
    int min = b[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (b[i] < min && b[i] % 2 != 0) {
            min = b[i];
            index = i;
        }
    for (int i = index; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        b[i] = b[i + 1];
    }
    b[n - 1] = 0;
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    money = 0;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i];
        money += b[i];
    }
    while (money % 2 != 0)
    {
        money -= min();
    }
    if (money % 2 == 0)
        if (money != 0)
            cout << money;
        else cout << "NIESTETY";


        system("pause");
}
```

Input = 2 4 3 3 3; output = 10 //Incorrect

Input = 4 2 3 3 3; Output = 12 //Correct

What is causing it? I think it may be min() function, but I am not sure

Comment: explain (edit your question) what the code is supposed to do (the abstract idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some more explanation would be helpful. What are you trying to achieve (especially with the odd/even logic? And what would you expect the first run to return?

Anyway, for the first run, min() first returns 2 and then 3. Subtracting both from the total money (15) gives 10.

My bet is that the min function should only return the smallest odd number, but when the first number in the array is the smallest one, it will be returned even when it is even. But as I said, it's hard to see the goal of this code without meaningful function names or more explanation. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, I just assumed that i[0] is the least but I forgot to check if it's %2 of not